# nvd3, lineWithFocusChart y-axis ticks are missing

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to work with  nvd3 lineWithFocusChart for time series data. But surprisingly y axis ticks are appearing as 000.00. The json data is in correct format as given in nvd3 website. I have placed my reference plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/QwMbTL4co0wMVKaQurxq?p=preview.

In order to sort the time series data, I have used the following function. With this, data is displayed properly except y-axis ticks issue. However tool tip is appearing fine with its correct values. What shall I do, to fix the appearance of y-axis ticks as 000.00

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(
                                series, index) {
                            series.values.sort(function(a, b) {
                                return a.x - b.x;
                            });
                        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chart width is hiding the values.

Add a `width : 700,`

And change the margins

```
margin : {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 100
},
```

**UPDATE :** You could also completely remove `width` and the `margin` , by default it will take the div size and re-sieze automatically.

Hope it helps

Comment: Probably the better solution, if Madasu wants to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to **not** format the Y axis :

```
yAxis: {
  axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
  tickFormat: function(d){
    return d;
  },
  rotateYLabel: false
},
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxnKPTzvF2hM1ZeQ0bu9?p=preview).

Comment: But the problem with this solution is, how can I do formatting to my y-ticks? For example, I would like to represent my y-ticks as the result which appears when I use something like, return '$' + d3.format('.02f')(d / 100).

Comment: @MadasuK See shaaber90's answer.